How to force my JAR to be executed on JDK 8?
I have a project Java (without maven or gradle, a "simple" one) and it has a lot of librairies to run it.
The project must be launched with JDK 8 otherwise it won't work because it's not compatible with higher versions.
I can run it with the command prompt : path/to/my/jdk8/java.exe -jar myJavaProject.jar
But I want it to be easy to run on any computer without searching the jdk8 folder...
How can I force the Jar to execute on jdk 8 then ? Or any solution to make it easier.
I have search on the internet, but only find some maven solution. But I don't know well maven...
Thank you so much in advance !

You can't ultimately restrict the Java version, but the best chance you have is to ship your own runtime But then of course, you need to produce an installer for each OS you want to support

have you set your JAVA_HOME and path to point to java 8? sounds like you havent done the necessary setup after installing the jdk

I have set JAVA_HOME and PATH but I don't know why it still java 21 active in my console so I force java8 with the folder path in my command...

8 must be before 21 in your PATH

When you launch it via path/to/my/jdk8/java.exe, neither the PATH nor JAVA_HOME variable matter.

@Holger - quite right ;)

You can't force your application to run on Java 8 if no Java 8 JRE is installed.
You can't force your application to run on Java 8 if the launcher can't find the installed Java 8 JRE.
So assuming that a Java 8 JRE is already installed and you know where it is installed, a couple of simple options are:

Use the absolute path to the (correct) java command; e.g.
/path/to/java8-jre/bin/java ... -jar yourApp.jar ...


Adjust the PATH environment variable so that the Java 8 java command is earlier on the path than other versions; e.g.
PATH=/path/to/java8-jre/bin:${PATH}



If you are trying to set this up so that some other user can run your app, the conventional solution to get them to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable, and have your app's launcher use that.  It could fall back to other mechanisms; e.g. using whatever the java command is found by searching PATH.  Of course, both of these assume that the user has a basic understanding of how environment variables work and (in the latter case) how the OS searches the command path.
Practical options for ensuring that the user >only< uses Java 8 to run your app are as follows:

Ship your application with an installer that also installs a suitable JRE.  There are lots of existing Q&As on how to do this.  Your installer then needs to configure the launcher for your app (e.g. script) with the location of the installed JRE.
This implies that you will need to provide separate installers for each (major) platform that you want to support.  However, there Java installer generators that can do most of the hard work for you.

Have your application >check< to see if the version of Java that is running it is suitable and exit if it isn't suitable.
You can do this by looking at the settings in the System properties object.  For example, the java.version property gives the major + minor + patch version number in a standard form.
You could do the version check in a launcher class.  If the version is acceptable, the launcher could then dynamically load and start the application proper.
If the app has to exit, it should provide some hints for the user on how to resolve the issue; i.e. instructions on installing a JRE,  setting JAVA_PATH, etcetera.




I have set JAVA_HOME and PATH but I don't know why it still java 21 active in my console so I force java8 with the folder path in my command.

Your problem is a simple one.  You have set PATH incorrectly.  Please read the answers to this Question:

Adding a directory to the PATH environment variable in Windows

The JAVA_HOME variable is only relevant if you have written a launcher (e.g. a BAT file) to launch your app, the launcher it uses that variable in the conventional way.
Note that solving this for >your< computer is much easier than solving it for >any< computer ... as your question asks.
